О чем говорят данные параметры о видеофайле
Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)

Хочу узнать, о чем говорят следующие параметры в строчке

3 kb/s
30 tbr
15360 tbn
60 tbc (default)


https://video.stackexchange.com/q/35455


битрейт, чем больше битрейт, тем лучше качество.

частота кадров.

из описания - Это базовая частота времени, которая указывает на количество временных единиц в секунду, используемых для измерения времени в видео. Другими словами - для синхронизации видео с аудио дорожками. У каждого кадра есть своя временная метка, указывающая на то, когда она воспроизводится.

базовая частота времени кодека в секунду. Почти то же самое, что и в 3 пункте, только применяется к кодеку.


Все взято из readme.
